# Past date should required to be freeze

Tags: javascript, jsp

When I entered the date manually then it will take a past date.So i tried with this code but this code do not allow a person to enter the date manually.So the Requirement here is that person can enter the date manually but the past date should be freeze.

```
<label for="exceptionBusinessHrs"><input id="exceptionBusinessDate" name="exceptionBusinessDate" onkeydown="return false" type="date" min='today' onchange="populateTime(this)"></label></th>
```

So I guess it's best to go with letting the user type the date and validate that the date in the input field is not in the past. Best option is to validate in the server side and as a bonus add Javascript validation. Server code should never rely on input validation done on browser `enter code here`because input from browser can be easily changed after javascript validation was done.Anyone help with code?

Comment: These need to be edits to your questions, not comments.

Comment: can anyone answer?